# How to implement Star Rating feedback system through Email notification in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, email-notifications

I am now implementing a Power Automate to receive the feedback from customer already received service from a store. The Power Automate will send an email to the Customer with a 7 stars rated visually appeared. So, customer should respond the rating by clicking the respective number star.

I am unable to understand how to display and handle the start visibility and click ability function with the Email actions in Power automate.

Kindly help me on this if any one has already implemented the same.

Thanks,Kailash

Comment: Look at Outlook actionable messages.

Comment: Actionable messages, or you could try to use Power Automate's built-in approval action with custom options.